# What is the difference between an ADT (Abstract Data Type) and a Container?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, theory

Can anyone explain the difference between an "abstract data type" and a "container"? I'm supposed to use them as part of a project for my Data Structures and Algorithms class, but I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Confusion note: often "ADT" is used to mean "algebraic data type" in this field, so make sure you define terms clearly and check existing uses.

Comment: thank you so much for asking this! I was also confused & trying to tell the difference

Answer (score 1):

An abstract data type is merely a logical description of the way the data will be stored and the operations that will be permitted on that data. For example, a stack is defined as a data type with the operations push, pop, etc. and LIFO access.

A container is a very abstract idea, but generally it implies (to me anyway) some form of encapsulation - in the sense that it might mask complexities of an underlying object, or possibly present a uniform interface to a range of different possible underlying objects. It's a word so firmly rooted in the programmer vocabulary that people use it all the time, and as such its meaning is very blurry.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be:

An ADT is characterized by a set of operations you can perform on it and a definition of their semantics. An ADT `reader` could be characterized by the operations

- `available(reader) -> number`
- `get_next(reader) -> element`

Where the type of `element` is not defined. Note that is not defined how a `reader` should work internally or where `get_next()` retrieves its elements from. Its abstract.

A container is just a (possibly abstract) data type that can contain instances of other data types, like a vector. Our`'reader` clearly need not be a container: The definition above says nothing that it will contain instances of other data types.

You could implement a `reader` that keeps reading from the keyboard and returning the keys pressed. This impelementation is clearly no container - it does not contain other elements.
you could also implement a `reader` that is a vector that also implements the two methods above. Eah call of `get_next()` could return its first element, then its second and so on. This implementation contains other elements, thus it would also be a container.

Answer (score 0):

From Skeina's The algorithm design manual here are some lines.

> We will focus on each of the three fundamental abstract data types
>   (containers, dictionaries, and priority queues) and see how they can
>   be implemented with arrays and lists.
>
> We use the term container to denote a data structure that permits
>   storage and retrievalofdataitemsindependent of
>   content.Bycontrast,dictionariesareabstract data types that retrieve
>   based on key values or content.

This means that containers(such as vectors), dictionaries(like hash tables) and PQs are all abstract data types. That means they are data structure ***concepts*** being implemented using the native data types like arrays or using linked types like pointers.